# Table fields in format in PDF report generator - Matlab

Tags: matlab, pdf, matlab-app-designer

When I save a table as PDF (using report generator) I do not get the numeric fields (Index1, Index2, Index3) shortG format (total of 5 digits). What is the problem and how can I fix it?

The code:

```
function ButtonPushed(app, event)
        import mlreportgen.dom.*;
        import mlreportgen.report.*

        format shortG;
        ID = [1;2;3;4;5];
        Name = {'San';'John';'Lee';'Boo';'Jay'};
        Index1 = [71.1252;69.2343245;64.345345;67.345322;64.235235];
        Index2 = [176.23423;163.123423654;131.45364572;133.5789435;119.63575647];
        Index3 = [176.234;16.123423654;31.45364572;33.5789435;11.6647];
        mt = table(ID,Name,Index1,Index2,Index3);


        d = Document('myPDF','pdf');
        d.OutputPath = ['E:/','temp'];

        append(d,'Table 1: '); 
        append(d,mt); 
        close(d);
        rptview(d.OutputPath); 
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix it, format your numeric arrays to character arrays with 5 significant digits before writing to PDF.

```
mt = table(ID,Name,f(Index1),f(Index2),f(Index3));
```

where,

```
function FivDigsStr = f(x)
%formatting to character array with 5 significant digits and then splitting. 
%at each tab. categorical is needed to remove ' 's that appear around char 
%in the output PDF file with newer MATLAB versions
%e.g. with R2018a, there are no ' ' in the output file but ' ' appears with R2020a
FivDigsStr = categorical(split(sprintf('%0.5G\t',x)));
%Removing the last (<undefined>) value (which is included due to \t)
FivDigsStr = FivDigsStr(1:end-1);
end
```

The above change gives the following result:

[image]

---

**Edit:**

To bring back the headers:

```
mt.Properties.VariableNames(3:end) = {'Index1', 'Index2', 'Index3'};
```

or in a more general way to extract the variable names instead of hardcoding them, you can use [`inputnames`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) to extract the variable names.

```
V = @(x) inputname(1);
mt.Properties.VariableNames(3:end) = {V(Index1), V(Index2), V(Index3)};
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. They are converted into string and they loss the header. Is it possible to convert it back to numeric and bring back the header?

Comment: Thanks a lot. any idea how to bring them back to numeric?

Comment: @Iroca For writing to PDF, it doesn't make any difference whether it's numeric or string

Comment: Indeed, but how can I omit the ' ' that will indicate numeric?

Comment: @Iroca There are no `' '` in the output PDF file

Comment: `1 'San' '1' '176.23' '176.23'` this is what I get in the PDF for example (I use 2020a)

Comment: You must be getting that in MATLAB; not PDF. Please double check. This is the PDF that you should be getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8E16.jpg

Comment: Which OS do you have btw?

Comment: win 10 pro version 1909

Comment: I am using R2018a on Win 10 home (10.0.17134)

Comment: @Iroca, I have updated it to work on R2020a as well.