# Format a DOM MATLAB table

Tags: matlab

Based on this question: [Table fields in format in PDF report generator - Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61673169/5698672), I converted the `p` table to be a DOM MATLAB Table. How can I color the header row, remove the underlining of its entries and apply the `tableStyle` on the rest of it.

With my code, I get all the table with the `LightBlue` color and the `tableStyle` is not applied.

**Code:**

```
function ButtonPushed(app, event)
import mlreportgen.dom.*;
import mlreportgen.report.*

ID = [1;2;3;4;5];
Name = {'San';'John';'Lee';'Boo';'Jay'};
Index1 = [1;2;3;4;5];
Index2 = [176.23423;163.123423654;131.45364572;133.5789435;119.63575647];
Index3 = [176.234;16.123423654;31.45364572;33.5789435;11.6647];
p = table(ID,Name,f(Index1),f(Index2),f(Index3));
V = @(x) inputname(1);
p.Properties.VariableNames(3:end) = {V(Index1), V(Index2), V(Index3)};

headerStyle = { BackgroundColor("LightBlue"), ...
    Bold(true) };

tableStyle = { Width("60%"), ...
    Border("single"), ...
    RowSep("solid"), ...
    ColSep("solid") };

p  = MATLABTable(p)

p.Style = headerStyle;
p.TableEntriesHAlign = 'center';

d = Document('myPDF','pdf');
d.OutputPath = ['E:/','temp'];
append(d,'Report for file: ');
append(d,p);
close(d);
rptview(d.OutputPath);
end

function FivDigsStr = f(x)
%formatting to character array with 5 significant digits and then splitting at each tab
FivDigsStr = categorical(split(sprintf('%0.5G\t',x)));
%Removing the last (empty) value (which is included due to \t)
FivDigsStr = FivDigsStr(1:end-1);
end
```

Comment: added the problem description.

Comment: btw you have [a DOM MATLAB Table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/mlreportgen.dom.matlabtable-class.html), not a [Formal Table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/mlreportgen.dom.formaltable-class.html). I have edited your question to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the variable `tableStyle` in which you defined the desired properties but you didn't set them. Also instead of setting the header as bold and light blue background, you are setting all the entries to have that.

The following code fixes that:

```
set(p, 'Width', '60%', 'Border', 'single',...
    'RowSep', 'solid', 'ColSep', 'solid',...
    'TableEntriesHAlign', 'center');
p.HeaderRule = '';  %To remove the underlining of header entries
p.Header.Style = headerStyle; %Setting the Header Style
```

[image]

Comment: OK. Can you please upload all the function? I do not what you removed and where the new code is located

Comment: Remove these two lines of your code `p.Style = headerStyle; p.TableEntriesHAlign = 'center';` and put my code there